# Simplify With Column in Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in Spark and i have applied some filters on this dataframe. Based on the records who passed through these filters, i have added a new column in dataframe. Refer to the code below:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA"), "rule1").otherwise(when(col("product_name").isin("XGE") && col("territory").isin("14721"), "rule2").otherwise(""))
val df_final = df_join.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name)
```

For better visibility purpose, i want to break down below code in multiple lines:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA"), "rule1").otherwise(when(col("product_name").isin("XGE") && col("territory").isin("14721"), "rule2").otherwise(""))
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Spark in SCALA and pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a better solution. If you want better readability then you can use udf function. But udf function would require columns to be serialized and deserialized. So you can use udf function as

```
def rule_name = udf((product_name: String, territory: String) => {
  val rule1ProductName = Array("N")
  val rule2ProductName = Array("XGE")
  val rule1Territory = Array("Metro", "GA")
  val rule2Territory = Array("14721")

  if(rule1ProductName.contains(product_name) && rule1Territory.contains(territory)) {
    "rule1"
  }
  if(rule2ProductName.contains(product_name) && rule2Territory.contains(territory)) {
    "rule2"
  }
  else ""
})
```

You can call the udf function as

```
val df_final = df_join.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name($"product_name", $"territory"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution you provided is the optimal one for this:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA"), "rule1").otherwise(when(col("product_name").isin("XGE") && col("territory").isin("14721"), "rule2").otherwise(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break your code into multiple lines like this:

```
val ruleName = 
    when(
        col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA"), "rule1"
    ).otherwise(
        when(
            col("product_name").isin("XGE") && col("territory").isin("14721"), "rule2"
        ).otherwise("")
    )
```

Or you can also do:

```
val firstCondition = col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA")
val secondCondition = col("product_name").isin("N") && col("territory").isin("Metro","GA")

val ruleName = when(firstCondition, "rule1").otherwise(
        when(secondCondition, "rule2").otherwise("")
    )
```

Whatever is more readable to you